# How to move Scaffold's body along with bottomSheet on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to achieve a particular behavior for my Scaffold when showing a BottomSheet. I want the Scaffold's body to move along with the bottom sheet. That is, when the Bottomheet comes out, the body of the Scaffold should go up with it. Like the image at the right. I'm not sure if my approach is the correct one. Maybe there are other better options to make this behavior possible.

[image]

The code with which I'm currently working is here:

```
 Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.purple[100],
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: Container(
      height: 900,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
              if (bottomSheetIsOpen) {
                bottomSheetIsOpen = false;
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    width: 300,
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorWidth: 3,
                      cursorColor: Colors.purple,
                      onTap: () {
                        bottomSheetIsOpen = true;
                        showBottomSheet(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => Container(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 200,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      showCursor: true,
                      readOnly: _readOnly,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 250,
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a ListView? If everything is going to be apart of a single scrollable then you can just make the last item in the ListView look like a draggable sheet

Comment: The thing is that I wouln't want the "bottom sheet" to be visible when scrolling. If I get what you mean, I think that would the case, wouldn't it? I'd like to have, for instance, a button whose function is to show automatically the bottomsheet, hidden till then.

Comment: Do you kinda of mean like when the bottom nav disappears on iOS Chrome? You have to swipe up to get it appear?

Comment: I'd rather like to open a "bottom sheet" with a button or something. With an event, let's say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this with a `Stack` and two `AnimatedPositioned` widget:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bottomsheet Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _isOpenBottomSheet = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bottomsheet Demo')),
      body: LayoutWithBottomSheet(
        children: List.generate(
          10,
          (index) => Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red.withGreen(index * 25),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                index.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ).toList(),
        bottomSheetChild: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
        bottomSheetHeight: 400,
        animationSpeed: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuad,
        isOpenBottomSheet: _isOpenBottomSheet.value,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _isOpenBottomSheet.value = !_isOpenBottomSheet.value;
        },
        child: Icon(_isOpenBottomSheet.value
            ? Icons.arrow_downward
            : Icons.arrow_upward),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LayoutWithBottomSheet extends HookWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final Widget bottomSheetChild;
  final Duration animationSpeed;
  final Curve animationCurve;
  final double bottomSheetHeight;
  final bool isOpenBottomSheet;

  const LayoutWithBottomSheet({
    Key key,
    this.children,
    this.bottomSheetChild,
    this.animationSpeed,
    this.animationCurve,
    this.bottomSheetHeight,
    this.isOpenBottomSheet,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scrollController = useScrollController();
    final childrenBottom = useState<double>();
    final bottomSheetBottom = useState<double>();
    useEffect(() {
      if (isOpenBottomSheet) {
        childrenBottom.value = bottomSheetHeight;
        bottomSheetBottom.value = 0;
        if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
          Future.microtask(
            () => _scrollController.animateTo(
              _scrollController.offset + bottomSheetHeight,
              duration: animationSpeed,
              curve: animationCurve,
            ),
          );
        }
      } else {
        childrenBottom.value = 0;
        bottomSheetBottom.value = -bottomSheetHeight;
        if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
          _scrollController.animateTo(
            _scrollController.offset - bottomSheetHeight,
            duration: animationSpeed,
            curve: animationCurve,
          );
        }
      }
      return;
    }, [isOpenBottomSheet]);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: animationSpeed,
          curve: animationCurve,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: childrenBottom.value,
          child: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: children,
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: animationSpeed,
          curve: animationCurve,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: bottomSheetBottom.value,
          height: bottomSheetHeight,
          child: bottomSheetChild,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I already tried it and it seems very doable to me. I will implement it in my app and I will give you feedback.

Comment: Great! Let me know.

Comment: I've tested it! There is just one issue. If you scroll completely to the bottom, and then open the "bottom sheet", with the bottom sheet opened, you can only partially scroll the items above. For example, I'm not able to ever see the red containers in that way. Let me know if I explained it well.

Comment: OK, I see. I thought it was what you wanted. Hahaha! I updated the answer fixing that.

Comment: Haha, no, you did understand well. Actually the first version of the code was better. What happens is that I am interested in being able to scroll the items that are behind the bottom sheet while the bottom sheet is open or unfolded. But although I can scroll, you cannot see all the objects, for instance, the very first objects that were initially at the top of the application. If you need, I could make a gif.

Comment: OK. Have a look. I changed the way I managed the ScrollController to follow your requirements.
I also reorganized the Widgets to have the BottomSheet functionality in a separate Layout Widget. I think it will be more readable and maintainable.
Let me know what you think!

Comment: I also uploaded a new animated GIF of the result.

Comment: I just tried it and it's perfect. I can say that you managed to meet all the requirements of what I had in mind. I plan to implement it now in an existing project, we will see how it will behave with more elements in play, but for now, thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228239/discussion-between-ivan-yoed-and-thierry).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing a bottom sheet, you can add a new widget to a Column

`reserve:true` is the key parameter for navigating to bottom

like:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    reserve: true,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        YourWidget(),
        if (isOpenBottomSheet)
          YourBottomSheet()
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

the complete example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isOpenBottomSheet = false;
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      isOpenBottomSheet = !isOpenBottomSheet;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        reverse: true,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            // your widget
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.black),
            // your bottom sheet
            if (isOpenBottomSheet) Container(height: 400, color: Colors.yellow),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good solution, but then you lose the animation that the bottomSheet has when appearing. In this case with the boolean, it just suddenly appears. Doesn't it?

Comment: yes, but the animation can be achieved with AnimatedContainer easily, you can change the height of the AnimatedContainer for example 0 to 400 and it will animate for you with the given duration and curve @IvánYoed

Comment: another workaround can be the same case and open the bottom sheet, you can make the latest item height the same as the bottom sheet

Comment: You lose the animation and you will also have to handle the scrolling down to the bottom of the main content if it's higher than the screen's height.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) with parallax effect:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      parallaxEnabled: true,
      parallaxOffset: 0.4
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very good solution to me, however I would rather achieve something without having to resort to a package.

Comment: no worries, suit yourself~ a single outcome can have many approaches, just choose what's the best for your own!